# I can't get the selected student in widget tweaks render_field using CreateView

Tags: django, forms, django-widget-tweaks

I am using the following code in views.py:

```
        class MatriculaCreateView(CreateView):
            template_name = "website/matricula.html"
            model = CursoPeriodoEstudante
            form_class = MatriculaMembroForm
            success_url = reverse_lazy("website:lista_estudantes")

            def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
                context = super(MatriculaCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
                context['estudante'] = Estudante.objetos.filter(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
                context['pk'] = self.kwargs['pk']
                return context
```

I create the following in forms.py:

```
        class MatriculaMembroForm(forms.ModelForm):

            class Meta:
                # Modelo base
                model = CursoPeriodoEstudante

                # Campos que estarão no form
                fields = [
                    'estudante',
                    'cursoPeriodo'

                ]
```

And finally in the template I created this page:

```
        {% extends "website/_layouts/base.html" %}

            {% load widget_tweaks %}

            {% block title %}Matricula de Membros{% endblock %}

            {% block conteudo %}
            <div class="container mt-5">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                  <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Matrícula de Membros</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">
                        Complete o formulário abaixo para matricular
                        um <code>Membro</code> em um evento.
                      </p>
                      <p>Membro: {{ estudante }} </p>
                      <form method="post">
                        <!-- Não se esqueça dessa tag -->
                        {% csrf_token %}

                        <!-- Estudante -->
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">Estudante</span>
                          </div>
                          {% render_field form.estudante class+="form-control" %}
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <!-- Curso -->
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">Evento</span>
                          </div>
                          {% render_field form.cursoPeriodo class+="form-control" %}
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="text-right">
                          <a href="{% url 'website:lista_estudantes' %}" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Voltar</a>
                          <button class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            {% endblock %}
```

The problem is, when the page opens, I want the field "Estudante" already filled with the one I selected in the view through the get_context_data (This field can be fixed). But the field always comes like this:[printscreen from page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzdNV.png). How can I fix to come with the student [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4fdI.png). What can I do? Thank you!

Ps.: I tried to put the following, but nothing happened...

```
            class MatriculaCreateView(CreateView):
                                template_name = "website/matricula.html"
                                model = CursoPeriodoEstudante
                                form_class = MatriculaMembroForm
                                success_url = reverse_lazy("website:lista_estudantes")

                                def get_initial(self):
                                    return {'estudante': Estudante.objetos.filter(id=self.kwargs['pk'])}

                                def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
                                    context = super(MatriculaCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
                                    context['estudante'] = Estudante.objetos.filter(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
                                    context['pk'] = self.kwargs['pk']
                                    return context
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the `get_initial()` method of `CreateView` to set initial values for your model:

```
def get_initial(self):
    return {'estudante': Estudante.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])}
```

Comment: I tried (you can see below) but nothing happened... :(

Answer (score 0):

I got it!
I should change the view to get, instead of filter (a query).

Thanks!